# using of grid view for managing the profit and loss account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a web application and in this project i have to manage the profit and loss account of a company.
I have two headers as **Income** and **Expenditure**

In the **Income** i have to show the details of income sources with amount group by date and in the similar way i have to show all the expenditures like salary,vat,etc. with amount group by dates.
How can i manage this through grid view so that i can calculate the net profit/loss.

Please help me with the suitable examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. It's pretty vague right now. Tell us the datasource, data model with which you are dealing with. Make a complete question rather than the outline of your requirement.

Comment: I am using the following tables:
Tbl_Sale(SaleId,Item,Quantity,Rate,TAX,Total,GrandTotal,Date)

Tbl_Purchase(PurchaseID,Item,Quantity,Total,Date)
Tbl_Expenses(ExpenseId,Total,Date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and the comment isn't explanatory in itself, so i am assuming bit of things myself so pardon me in that case.

I assume you want to Show data from Tbl_Sale under the Income header and data from Tbl_Purchase under Expenditure header.

For that, you will need to have two grid controls one for Tbl_Sale and one for for Tbl_Purchase(Set their respective data sources). Both of these controls orientation is needed to be set vertically rather than the default horizontal. Include the columns in gridview for those values which you want to display : like Item and Amount.

For Total, you will need to have a function which sums up the Entire Sale table and Entire Purchase table and stores the value in some temp field like TotalSumForSale and TotalSumForPurchase and then display them at the bottom of your grid controllers. You can't have them inside the Gridview control

Comment: exactly i want to do the same sir,bt under the expenditure header i have to show other expenditures than the purchase.

Comment: then you need to make a ViewModel class(call it expenditure.cs) that fetches the different values from different tables and then set it as datasource for your Gridview controller under Expenditure. *On a side note, ViewModel is a merger of two or different models into one*